# Mendeley italicise species name in the title

Tags: mendeley

So i know that `<i>Text</i>` in the mendeley titles will italicise the names, but is there a way to edit a lot of references quickly? I've been doing it with a find and replace in word, but every time mendeley updates the references, it removes my manual changes.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but many text editors will accept `CTRL+I`

Comment: Mendeley https://www.mendeley.com/ is a reference manager. I can do CTRL+I in word and do the changes, sure, but I currently have about 100 references and each entry has a species name that i need to italicise.
The other problem being that if I do manual edits, it doesn't save the edits when i add or refresh the references

Comment: What I mean is, copy it into a program like notepad++ and use regex to surround the species with i tags this, then copy it back (assuming you have a list of species you want this to apply to) ?

Comment: probably, i'll have a look into how to export the information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to type in by hand   by hand - which in my opinion is a shortcoming of Mendeley. You can italicise, bold, superscript, change case, etc. words in Endnote. Also, when you export from Endnote as xml file, the code to italicize is incorporated where relevant as  But all this is lost when you import the xml file into Mendeley which means that in my case, I have to recode thousands of records if I want to use Mendeley.

Comment: It seems like you’re just repeating the question. Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the references is the task of the Citation Style. Such a citation style can be choosen using the plugin for the word processer (MS Word or LibreOffice) 
see Dropdown-Field "Style"

Answer (score 0):

Please put `<i>` and ended by `<i/>` at the word/words you want it to italic, e.g., `<i>Oryza sativa</i>` it will become *Oryza sativa* in the title. 
The `<i>` and `</i>` will not be printed by Mendeley.

Comment: If you read the question closely, you will see that Nathaniel already knows everything you have said here.  Do you have an answer to his question?